# Can I get message when I show UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, notifications, uialertview

I want to get message when system show UIAlertView so I can pause my game.

Anyone know how to figure out that?

The UIAlertView is not controlled by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application delegate's [`applicationWillResignActive:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive:) will be called on interrupts. You can handle the pause there or you can even listen to the [`UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification) in your view controller and pause the game there.

You can look at [`this part`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html) of the *iOS Application Guide* that details the life cycle of the application and state transitions.

Comment: The alert is in app ,controlled by gamecenter.

Answer (score 8):

A system alert is normally displayed in its own `UIWindow`. Install handlers for the `UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification` and `UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification` notifications to track when a `UIWindow` becomes visible and hidden respectively:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(aWindowBecameVisible:)
                                              name:UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification
                                            object:nil];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(aWindowBecameHidden:)
                                              name:UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification
                                            object:nil];
```

In the handlers, grab the `UIWindow` that changes state from the `object` property of the notification:

```
- (void)aWindowBecameVisible:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIWindow *theWindow = [notification object];
    NSLog(@"Window just shown: %@", theWindow);
}

- (void)aWindowBecameHidden:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIWindow *theWindow = [notification object];
    NSLog(@"Window just hidden: %@", theWindow);
}
```

Finally, check that `theWindow` contains a subview of type `UIAlertView`.

Answer (score 1):

If your UIAlertView is from Third party app (not from your app) then you can implement below delegate methods to pause and resume game.

To Pause game

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
}
```

To Resume game

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
}
```

For example if you receive call or SMS you can use above delegate to pause/resume game.

Comment: Actually when I disconnect to the apple server.GameCenter will show UIAlertView.I want to do something at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Just make this:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
//pause
}
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
//resume
}
```