# Is there a notification on iOS if a UIAlertView is shown?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsnotifications, nsnotificationcenter

Wondering if there is a notification available if a `UIAlertView` pops up?
Background: my app asks the user for a PIN after a period of inactivity but I would like to prevent it if an alert is on screen.
I don't want to go through my code and find all alerts and disable the PIN checker, instead a notification would be awesome. Any hope with `NSNotification`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found the answer. It is hidden in here:

[Can I get message when I show UIAlertView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607170/can-i-get-message-when-i-show-uialertview)

If you listen to the "`UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification`" notification, it will also fire for your own alerts, not only for system alerts.
For your own alerts, the application does not resign activiation however.