# How to respond to UIImagePickerController Generated UIAlertView

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, uialertview

I am using UIImagePickerController to capture video from my app and i have set video maximum duration to 30 seconds. When that 30 seconds limit is reached. I get an alert with a message "maximum video recording limit reached" **produced by UIImagePickerController** and it stops capturing video.

What I want is that I want to respond to that alert that is generated automatically when 30 seconds limit is reached. I want to perform some action when "OK" button of that alert is pressed. I have implemented all the delegate methods of UIAlertView but it does come in any method when I press OK button.

Please help me how I can respond to that alert?

Comment: Please show the code that you use to generate the alert

Comment: Can you get some `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`'s method called when the time exceeds? For example `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`

Comment: UIAlertViewDelegateProtocol is the correct answer, just be sure to set the delegate and check with index corresponds to "OK" using a breakpoint.

Comment: In UIAlertViewDelegateProtocol Implement method '- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex' ; and Button Index will be pressed button Index. for more info go to [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html)

Comment: As I said I have implemented all the delegate methods of UIAlertview but it is not responding to any of these method because i am not generating that alert through my code. It is generated by UIImagePickerController itself when 30 seconds limit is reached. And i have no way to set that particular alert'delegate to self.

Comment: @Fogmeister I am using generating that alert through my code. It is generated automatically when 30 seconds limit is reached.

Comment: @Andrea I think the alert is pop up by the system. Is there a chance to set delegate for a system alert view like this?

Comment: @onevcat . You are the first person who read my question thoroughly and got my point.

Comment: @onevcat If is generated by the system I don't think is possible, but you get the point probably you''l have a chance to intercept something UIImagePickerControllerDelegate or registering to some sort of Notification.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a notification on iOS if a UIAlertView is shown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692205/is-there-a-notification-on-ios-if-a-uialertview-is-shown)

Comment: is it any way to remove or hide generated alert ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use all those delegate methods because you didn't initiate the `UIAlertView` so you can't set his delegate...

The only thing I can think about is to do somethong like listening to the `UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification` to detect when an alert is shown and to the `UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification` notification to detect when it disappears.

You should know that those notification will fire for all kind of components that uses their own `UIWindow` such as `UIActionSheet` or the keyboard, so you need to make sure this is the right one (maybe check to see if there is a UIAlertView in one of the subviews..)

Answer (score 1):

Set yourself as a delegate of your `UIImagePickerController`, and implement the [UIImagePickerControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html) protocol. Specifically, the following method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)
```

Comment: Nops..Your solution will not work. A little clarification. - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)   is called immediately when 30 seconds time limit is reached. IT IS NOT CALLED WHEN I PRESS OK BUTTON OF UIAlertview. I want to perform some task immediately after pressing OK button.

Comment: In that case, I'm starting to think @Eyal's answer is the closest you'll get.

Answer (score -1):

Use [UIAlertViewDelegateProtocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html)

Form docs

> alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:
>
> Sent to the delegate when the user
> clicks a button on an alert view.
>
> - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex Parameters alertView The
>   alert view containing the button. buttonIndex The index of the button
>   that was clicked. The button indices start at 0. Discussion The
>   receiver is automatically dismissed after this method is invoked.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 2.0 and later. Declared In UIAlertView.h

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        // do stuff for button index 0,ie cancel button and sthe same for other button  indeces
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Please refer this tutorials : http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uialertview/  you can get more ideal about this :

```
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello World!"
                                                  message:@"This is your first UIAlertview message."
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Button 1"
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Button 2", @"Button 3", nil];
[message show];


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"Button 1"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Button 1 was selected.");
    }
    else if([title isEqualToString:@"Button 2"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Button 2 was selected.");
    }
    else if([title isEqualToString:@"Button 3"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Button 3 was selected.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I AM NOT CREATING THAT ALERT PRO-GRAMMATICALLY IN MY CODE...... IT IS AUTOMATICALLY CREATED BY UIImagePickerController.

Comment: - (void)picturePopup:(UIAlertView *)picturePopup clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex  use this method may be its working.

Comment: Its not a delegate method of UIAlertView.