# Notification or delegate called when UIAlertView is hidden/removed

Tags: ios, uialertview, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications, uialertviewdelegate

I am trying to find what delegate/protocol or even notification is called when an alert view is hidden or shown.  Do these events trigger a notification or callback that I can listen for?

I know the UIAlertView protocol, but that's not what I am looking for, I am looking for the actual display and hide events to perform actions after they are completed.

Does this exist?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I get message when I show UIAlertView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607170/can-i-get-message-when-i-show-uialertview)

Comment: I hope my answer can help you a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know about AlertViews you've presented yourself, you're looking for [UIAlertViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html) protocol

`didPresentAlertView:` and `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:`

If you want to know when an AlertView has been shown by the OS, you can try `UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification` and `UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification` in the [UIWindow class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html), then check if the `windowLevel` property is equal to `UIWindowLevelAlert`

Comment: i think that was meant, when he said "I know the UIAlertView protocol, but that's not what I am looking for"

Comment: Thank you the didbecomvisible notification hidden notification were what I was looking for... Is there a more unified document regarding notifications that are sent?  I assumed this, and other notifications I would need exist, but finding documentation about them seems hap hazard at best.

Comment: @user282172 : **`UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification` & `UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification` are not `UIAlertView` specific notifications**. They're `UIWindow` specific and hence these notifications will be posted when the app is shown/hidden i.e. app launch / app goes to background / app comes in foreground. It has nothing to do with `alertView` being shown or hidden. **It's just an indirect way to check**. There are **No** `UIAlertView` notifications (_kindly don't downvote answers without understanding the specifics_)

Comment: I downvoted your answer static, because you clearly didn't read my question. You cited the UIAlertView Protocol as an answer when I clearly stated in my question that I was aware of it and that it was not providing what I was seeking.

Comment: @user282172 : my answer was no different than the comment above (_only difference, i assumed you were aware of Apple's notification naming convention that if the notification name begins with `UIWindow`, it's a `UIWindow` notification. If it begins with `UIKeyboard` it's a `UIKeyboard` notification_) PS: the downvote didn't bother me, it was the invalidity of the downvote. A downvote + comment would have been appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to check `NSNotifications` is adding that code to your **AppDelegate.m**:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notification:) name    :nil object:nil];

    return YES;
}

-(void)notification:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Notification name is %@, \n sent by %@\n\n",[notification name], [[notification object] description] );
}
```

I tested this code triggering `UIAlertViews` and I never receive an `NSNotification` related to.
So probably there aren't `NSNotification`related to `UIAlertViews`.