# Detect when system alertView willAppear/willDismiss

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, key-value-observing

I want to detect when system alertView, like in-app purchase confirmation alert appears on screen.
I'm trying to add key value observer to UIApplication, but it doesn't work.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "windows", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.allZeros, context: &myContext)
```

Comment: More than likely because iOS 8 doesn't use UIAlertView anymore, so alerts don't have a separate window anymore either

Comment: may I ask whether there is any specific reason why you need to know about the system alerts? it is quite irregular monitoring the system popups like this.

Comment: I want to start animating spinner, and when alert popup stop animating.

Comment: Take a look at this: maybe it can help you:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607170/can-i-get-message-when-i-show-uialertview][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607170/can-i-get-message-when-i-show-uialertview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that I wanted, but it works for me.

```
NotificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "applicationWillResignActive", name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "applicationDidBecomeActive", name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)

func applicationDidBecomeActive()
{
    if Library.isPurchasing
    {
        Application.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    }
}

func applicationWillResignActive()
{
    if Library.isPurchasing
    {
        Application.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    }
}
```

Comment: in swift 5 : 
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationWillResignActive), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)

Answer (score 0):

Look at `UIAlertViewDelegate` documentation. There are methods like `willPresentAlertView:`, `didPresentAlertView:`, `alertView:willDismissWithButtonIndex:`, and `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:`.